# Ruby Restclient.delete with request body and content-type

Tags: ruby

Could you please correct the mistake I make here while calling http delete.
I get InternalServerError with no further explanation.

The same call works fine on FireFox RESTClient plugin.

**Sample RestClient**

```
require "rest_client"
data= {"name" => "foo"}
res = RestClient.delete(url, data.to_json)
```

Throws: /lib/restclient/request.rb:72:in `process_url_params': undefined method`delete_if' for # (NoMethodError)

**Sample net/http**

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('some ip valid', port)
headers = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
data = {"name" => "foo"}
resp, data = http.delete(path, headers)
```

Throws: Net::HTTP InternalserverError

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and got it working by removing the json data part.

```
def doRestDelete(url, values)
    puts "URL: ",  url
    jsonValues = values.to_json
    puts jsonValues
    begin
        raw = RestClient.delete url # removed this bit --->  , jsonValues
        puts raw
    rescue => e
        abort(e.response)
    end
    return JSON.parse(raw)
end
```